# Are there reasons for duties of the heart?

Tags: mitzvah, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, faith-bitachon-emunah, chovos-halvavos

For example, is there a reason for the mitzvah of bitachon? Of emunah? I think this is important to know because the Chovos Halevavos [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Duties_of_the_Heart%2C_Third_Treatise_on_Service_of_God.3.22?lang=bi) appears to say one should do rational mitzvos both because God said **and** for their rationale. But I wonder if the idea of טעמי המצוות is at all applicable to duties of the heart. It seems strange to consider that there may be an underlying "reason" for mitzvos such as emunah and bitachon...

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what you mean to those unfamiliar with what you're discussing. For example, what do you mean a mitzvah of bitachon. How does it differ from emunah. What are duties of the heart. Why do you think duties of the heart shouldn't have a rationale?

Comment: Regarding emunah, the sefer HaChinuch suggests a rationale

Comment: Read the introduction of Chovos Halevavos.

Comment: But this is an odd question because objectively I would have far more difficulty trying to find a rationale for the *mitzvos maasiyos*?